# Rails devise email authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am new to rails and i'm using a [rails devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) template application. When i enter my email and try reset my password, i get the following error: `authentication required`

[image]

What does this mean?

UPDATE: As suggested by trh, the error is coming from `secrets.yml`
Here is what it currently looks like:

```
development:
admin_name: Ben
admin_email: admin@exmaple.com
admin_password: password
email_provider_username: "username@gmail.com" #eg. ben@gmail.com
email_provider_password: "password"
domain_name: example.com
secret_key_base: #30 digit code
```

Is it possible that the error comes from the way i have declared the email provider username and password? does it need to be in the form `<%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>`?

Comment: Do you have email set up in your environment config so devise can end messages?  That's an email server error.

Comment: Im not sure. Which file would it be in? @trh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mail config is done in: `config/environments/development.rb`

Since the RailsApps template already has that set up for gmail, you need to change the data (username, passsword, etc) in `config/secrets.yml`.  If you plan to use SMTP instead (for a non-google address) then you'll need to change your development.rb file to match that.  For instance you'll have to change the domain host, so if your mail provider is outlook.com you're config will look something like:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.live.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :user_name            => 'noreply@example.com',
 :password             => 'password',
 :domain               => 'example.com',
 :authentication       => 'plain'
}
```

Comment: I have set up the username, password and gmail in `sectrets.yml` for development. I am assuming i dont need to set it up for production at the moment. For simplicity, i would like to use gmail so i dont need to implement above code. But it still doesnt work?

Comment: Did you restart the rails server?

Comment: Assuming you are adding an actual gmail address and gmail password, then it's perfectly fine to do it this way, just make sure you don't commit this file to a git repository, or the password will be there forever.

Comment: the email password or the admin password?

Comment: email_provider_username & email_provider_password have to be actual gmail credentials.

Comment: After playing around with it, i have gotten it to work. Im not sure why, perhaps i had a typo. Now i have the error `accounts.google.com/signin/continue?` but this is a seperate issue which i can solve. Thank you very much!